# Finding Inverse of a matrix using elementary transformations

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

So I have to find the Inverse of A.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$
By using elementary row or column transformations..

The method involves writing:

$A A¯¹ = I $

And then performing the same set of operations on both A and I, to convert A to I and then we get the Inverse on the R. H. S of the equation.

So by a series of transformations I get 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

It is wrong but my steps seemed to be legit but it took too many operations thus mistake is possible.

So can someone suggest me some steps so that A converts to I in minimum transformations.

I = Identity Matrix

Comment: Did you write $A^{-1} = [ A | I]$ and perform the **same** operations on $[A | I]$ when reducing?

Comment: No I wrote A * A¯¹ = I and then performed same operations on  both A and I

Comment: See example 1: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~annav/0290H/row_reduction.pdf . Make sure to also understand example 2 - when there is no inverse!

Comment: Yes did the same thing I just want help on the transformation part

Comment: Try this - I just did and it works. http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi

Comment: @Moo Yes it worked. Thanks!